# Testing orthogonal contrasts with bayesian one way Anova R

Tags: r, bayesian

I am testing the impact of two treatments on blood sugar level.
The structure of my data is similar to the following:

```
ID <- c('1','2','3','4','5','6')
GROUP <- c('0','1','0','2','1','2')
DIFF_GLYCEMIA <- c('12','14','11','7.5','12','8')
DF <- data.frame(ID, GROUP, DIFF_GLYCEMIA)
DF$GROUP <- as.factor(DF$GROUP)
DF$DIFF_GLYCEMIA <- as.numeric(DF$DIFF_GLYCEMIA)
```

I want to test the specific prediction of a linear impact of group: meaning that being in group 0 (control) will have a smaller impact on glycemia than being in group 1 (drugs) which impact will be smaller than the impact of being in group 2 (drugs + psychological intervention). Usually, I create orthogonal contrasts as follow and if c1 is significant but not c2, it confirms my hypothesis.

```
c1 <- c(-1 , 0, 1)
c2 <- c( 1,  -2, 1 )
contrasts(DF$GROUP) = cbind(c1, c2)
model <- aov(DIFF_GLYCEMIA ~ GROUP, data = DF)
summary.aov(model, split=list(GROUP=list("c1"=1, "c2" = 2)))
```

But this time, I need to do a bayesian anova and I don't know how to do that. All the solution seems to integrate the contrast but rather give me one output (solution 1), or compare the model (solution 2) which seems to answer a different question.

```
# solution 1

contrasts(DF$GROUP) = cbind(c1, c2)
anovaBF(DIFF_GLYCEMIA ~ GROUP, data = DF)
# output : GROUP : X.XXXX ±0.0X%


# solution 2

generalTestBF(DIFF_GLYCEMIA~c1+c2, data=DF, whichModels="all")
# output : c1 : X.XXXX ±0.0X%
#          c2 : X.XXXX ±0.0X%
#      c1 + c2: X.XXXX ±0.0X%
```

Does anyone know how to do the same anova analysis but bayesian ?
Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/47044/87002

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Phil. Unfortunately, I think it is not answering my question because their results are not splitted by contrast..